# Can someone steal your information from the motherboard of your iPhone?

Tags: iphone, encryption

My iPhone has recently been stolen. I got a new phone with the same number and now I’m getting texts saying that they are going to sell the motherboard of my phone and that any personal information may be leaked. The phone was locked on Find My friends so it’s pretty much a dud phone for them. They are wanting me to erase the phone from Find My. Is there any way that they can get my personal information from the motherboard of the phone?

Comment: Might even consider reversing the bluff if you can respond to them.  "Point out" that although they cannot get any information from the phone, _you_ can, and should the phone happen to mysteriously appear on your doorstep, you won't need to send police to its current location.

Answer (score 2):

`Activation Lock` is a feature that's designed to prevent anyone else from using your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, if it's ever lost or stolen.  When your iPhone was lost, you did the right thing by enabling it. As long as `Activation Lock` is enabled on your lost or stolen iPhone, nobody can use it.

This is why they are trying to frighten you and blackmailing you to turn off the `Activation Lock`:

> They are wanting me to erase the phone from find my.

**Don't do it**. There is no realistic way they can get your personal data from the iPhone motherboard as it is encrypted. (Even if it was possible, decrypting the data would still take them a lot of time and money - more than what the iPhone itself is worth it. And no petty thief will waste their time and money on such thing where they won't make any profit.)

What you should also do now is to [remotely *erase all data* on your stolen phone](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/icloud/mmfc0ef36f/1.0/icloud/1.0):

1. Go to [iCloud Find Devices](https://www.icloud.com/find).
2. In `Find Devices` on iCloud.com, click **All Devices**, then select the device you want to erase.
3. Click *Erase iPhone*.
4. Enter your Apple ID and password.
5. If the device is online all data on it will be deleted. Otherwise, it will be deleted when it comes online.

(**Note**: Activation Lock will still be enabled after erasing a device).

Answer (score 2):

#### You are protected.

> … and now I’m getting texts saying that they are going to sell the motherboard of my phone and that any personal information may be leaked.

**This is not feasible.**

First, you’re iPhone was put into “Locked Mode” meaning, until you remove this, nothing is getting access.  Secondly, they cannot remove the storage (chip) then attach it (solder) to another iPhone to get access.  This is due to the secure enclave that holds the keys to the encrypted storage device.  This chip “sits” between the OS and storage.  The only thing they’ll be able to do (theoretically) is wipe the storage to make it work on that different logic board.

> They are wanting me to erase the phone from Find My.

This is because they can’t access your data; Find My worked exactly as it was designed.   It goes to say that you should definitely not do this.

When you enable Find My it immediately locks the device with a passcode; you took exactly the right course of action.  [Apple prescribes the next steps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210515):

- Send the command to erase the device
- Report it to AppleCare (if covered)
- (My suggestion) Report the loss/theft to  your carrier so they can black list it effectively blocking the IMEI number from all carrier networks.

#### TL;DR

You are correct; locking your phone only results in them being in possession of a brick.  Find My has secured the device and the contents are secured behind the secure enclave.  If you haven’t already done so, send the command to wipe the deivce.

And…never, ever disable Find My until/unless the device is physically back in your hands.

Answer (score 0):

I would doubt it without some serious Mission Impossible skills which I doubt any petty criminal would have. But if you are concerned about it, you might find the answers in Apple's Platform Security Guide available on their developers site. It's intended for people who develop software but it goes into some really detailed descriptions of the length's Apple goes to in order to keep your data safe at the hardware level. It's actually a fascinating read, and from what I remember of it, everything is heavily encrypted with keys that are stored in a segregated and secure chip that is pretty much impossible to get into. Just ask the FBI, NSA and all the other agencies that have been trying to force Apple to give them access for years. So personally I wouldn't worry. It's far more likely IMHO that those who have your phone are just trying to scare into giving them a free phone. If you can make their life difficult, why not. It's the least they deserve. Alternatively you could tell them you have to do it in person and give them the address of a local Police station :-)

Comment: Do you mean this guide? https://help.apple.com/pdf/security/en_US/apple-platform-security-guide.pdf